# How the main works in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I got a doubt while working on my IOS project, for our testing purpose, we wrote a piece of code like this in main...

```
printf("start\n");
FILE *fp = fopen("/Users/gui_test/Desktop/ritun/hello_test/hello_test/expt.txt", "a + b");

int a = 5, b = 5;
int c = a + b;

fprintf(fp, "%d\t", c);
fflush(fp);

fclose(fp);

printf("end \n");
```

I have commented out the below line in main to test file writing.

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ofi_video_monetAppDelegate class]));
```

Answer is written into file successfully but twice, Anyone have any idea why is this? Other than main() if I try anywhere else, it is writing only one time, what is happening in main.

Comment: is also `start\n` logged twice? would you replace it by "start-main"? and what happens if you do no comment out `UIApplicationMain`?

Comment: No start and end are printed only once. If I not commented that line. than it is writing properly in file

Comment: My guess is that your code is duplicated. There is no other explanation I can see...

Comment: your `fopen` file mode is append.  Perhaps you are seeing duplicate entries in the file as an artifact of prior runs.

Comment: I have written this piece of code only one time, I'm deleting the created file every time.

Comment: Could it be that application is opened twice when run? Maybe debugger could be the reason for that.. In what modes have you been trying that? Debug, release, normal opening on device? It could be that main returns with a certain exit code for the first time that relaunches the application with some new parameters needed on the OS.. Anyway, you could also try to log the exit code returned by main and maybe time of execution.

Comment: @MaticOblak If the app run twice, that log start and end also should print right, but that is not printing.

Comment: Not really.. Every time the app starts, the log clears, right? Also if the app for some reason exited and reentered your log might not even work.

Comment: @MaticOblak Got a point to think :)

Comment: Same goes for breakpoints and such tools... Actually the only indicator for such behavior I can think of is the one you made: write something into some file.

Comment: @MaticOblak Do you think break point also won't hit next time, if it launches again?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19823/discussion-between-matic-oblak-and-newbee)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning 0 by commenting out the following line causing the main called twice internally,

```
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ofi_video_monetAppDelegate class]));
```

I have returned 1, it works fine, one entry in file, no duplicates.

Comment: If any one knows exact reason for that.. Please post it so everyone can know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Link](http://cupsofcocoa.com/2010/09/03/objective-c-lesson-1-hello-world/).
It explains the use of main function.

> main is a function that is where every C or C-based program begins. It
>   is a reserved name, which means that you can’t have a function named
>   main. The word int that precedes main is a declaration of the return
>   type of the function.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
        // memory management
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        // printing on the log
        NSLog (@"Hello, World!");

       [pool drain];
//The final line tells the main method to return the value 0. Remember that the int the preceded main tells the system that this function will return a value. This value is 0. By convention, a return value of zero indicates that the function was successful.
       return 0;
}
```

Also see [NSAutoreleasePool](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSAutoreleasePool)